# C++17's Variadic `using`: Discrepencies between compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, c++17, clang++

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gNzhE-Tn40&list=PLs3KjaCtOwSZ2tbuV1hx8Xz-rFZTan2J1&index=50) on a topic about `C++17's Variadic using`. So out of curiosity I tried this code snippet here exactly as is within my own IDE `MS Visual Studio 2017 CE` with compiler language settings to `c++17`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename ... B>
struct Merged : B... {
    template<typename ... T>
    Merged( T && ... t ) : B( std::forward<T>( t ) )... {
    }

    using B::operator()...;
};

template<typename ... T>
Merged( T... ) -> Merged<std::decay_t<T>...>;

int main() {
    const auto l1 = []() { return 4; };
    const auto l2 = []( const int i ) { return i * 10; };

    Merged merged( l1, l2, []( const double d ) { return d * 3.2; } );

    std::cout << merged() << "\n";
    std::cout << merged( 5 ) << "\n";
    std::cout << merged( 4.5 ) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Of course it fails to compile. So I then ventured to websites with built in compilers. I tried using [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#) and I used a majority of the compiler versions available on that website setting the appropriate compiler options for `c++17`. They all failed to compile. I eventually tried [WandBox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zUdebsp7ELIuGQKA)
and it only seems to compile for `Clang` versions 5.0 and higher. None of the `GCC` compilers would compile it from either `Compiler Explorer` or `WandBox`, and the only compilers that would compile and run it as is are the `Clang` compilers at `WandBox`.

I'm not interested in actually trying to make this work; I was just curious or interested in the subject of the video itself. When I tried to implement the code it became vary curious and apparent on how much of a variation there is from one compiler of the C++ language to another.

Why does it appear in this specific case that `Clang's` versions 5.0+ are the only ones to fully support this feature of the `C++17` language with the syntax currently being the way it is?

Comment: Note that the `decay` in your deduction guide is unnecessary, `Merged(T...) -> Merged<T...>` already means that.

Comment: @Barry I just came across a video that I was watching; and was just curious about how different compilers treat it. I never expected this to be a duplicate question; nor was I truly interested in any of the errors or warnings. But I do appreciate your tip about the deduction guide.